# react this.props.function is undefined even I bind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bind

I am pretty much struggling with this. React keep saying my function is undefined but the function is working.

I have a parent component and a child component, I want to pass down a function from parent to child. This is what I did:

parent :

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Child } from 'components';

    export default class Parent extends Component{ 
        constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.myFunc = this.myFunc.bind(this); 
        }

        myFunc (data) {
           console.log("wowow I got you!", data)
        }

       render(){
        return (
           <div>
              <Child thatFunc={this.myFunc} />
           </div>
        )
       }
    }
```

child:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    export default class Child extends Component {
          constructor(props) {
               super(props);
          }

          componentDidMount(){
               this.props.thatFunc("i got the function!")
          }

          render(){
             return (
                <div> do this do that </div>
             )
          }
    }
```

So I do get the console.log correct as " wowow I got you i got the function!".
But, I got this as well: Uncaught TypeError: this.props.thatFun is not a function

Does anyone knows why?Thankkkk you!

Comment: Just curious, is this line: `import { Child } from 'components';` just an example or do you actually have that in your code? First of all this isn't a correct import, second of all the Child doesn't contain any `Child` named export so you should get rid of the parentheses.

Comment: Running this on [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0m2vpk8jop) doesn't seem to produce the same error

Comment: Have you tried something like `const { thatFunc } = this.props` and then do `console.log(thatFunc)` and see what you get

Comment: @TomekRychtyk thank you for your respond. this is just a sample, real code is far more longer than this. i just want to extract related pieces. The Child component was imported and exported by index.js inside component folder, which is not a default export.

Comment: hi there, I tried your suggestion and this is what i got:console logged twice. first time: ƒ (e){console.log("wowow i got you",e)} && “wowow I got you i got the function!” second time: undefined && uncaught typeerror. Is it something related to the componentdidmount life cycle?I do have some data coming from backend.

Comment: In this case you'll need to show us more related code because the sample one you provided should work just fine. Do you use async imports by any chance? If you get your console.log twice in `componentDidMount` it means the components mounts then unmounts and then mounts again (if you add a console.log in `componentWillUnmount` there's a good chance you'll see something too).

Comment: @Aaqib hi there thank you for your response! I tried your suggestion and this is what i got:console logged twice. first time: ƒ (e){console.log("wowow i got you",e)} && “wowow I got you i got the function!” second time: undefined && uncaught typeerror. Is it something related to the componentdidmount life cycle?I do have some data coming from backend.

Comment: @Aaqib no worries guys I got it. I have a list of children and I just need ONE child to be able to get this function, but I didn't filter it properly. How silly! Thank you so much for your attention, I guess the console.log showed up twice pointed out the situation. Thanks again!

Comment: @TomekRychtyk  no worries guys I got it. I have a list of children and I just need ONE child to be able to get this function, but I didn't filter it properly. How silly! Thank you so much for your attention, I guess the console.log showed up twice pointed out the situation. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code WORKS. It was an unrelated bug. I have a list of children and I just need ONE child to be able to get this function, but I didn't filter it properly. How silly! Thank you so much for your attention, the code works just fine. I will close this question.